# Flutter custom slider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to make slider that behave different from default one. So the blue pointer here stay fixed while the background is moving and changing the value. Have no idea how to make it (newbie with Flutter) [slider img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI9aJ.png)

Comment: You need to make ListView.builder and in that builder you need to build the scrollbar. axis needs to be horizontal.
Later you need to update the state with current scroll offset, and display the data based on that offset. If no one does it, I can do it but later

Comment: Thank you. Dealing with your advice i've found the "scroll snap list" package - i think digging into this package will solve my problem, it handle the snapping behavior and has onItemFocus property